# Why my float variable always at 0 even i set it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just start making a game with Unity and Visual Studio, i have a bit confuse that why my **Speed** value always at zero even i set it equal to another variable.

```
public class Ballista : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public GameObject arrowPrefab;
    public float speed = 10f;

    public float startTimeHold;
    public float holdDownTime;
    public float arrowSpeed = 100f;
    public float finalSpeed;


    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            startTimeHold = Time.time;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.M))
        {
            holdDownTime = Time.time - startTimeHold;
            Shoot();
            finalSpeed = holdDownTime * arrowSpeed;
        }
        
        Debug.Log("holddowntimeis: " + holdDownTime);
        Debug.Log("final speed is: " + finalSpeed);

    }
    
    public void Shoot()
    {
        GameObject arrowGO = (GameObject)Instantiate(arrowPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

and this is the script that my **speed** value always zero

```
{
    Rigidbody2D rgBody2D;
    public GameObject ballista;
    private float speed;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rgBody2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        \\ i though the code below will set my speed equal to my finalSpeed but it still 0
        speed = ballista.GetComponent<Ballista>().finalSpeed;

        Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        Debug.Log("speed: " + speed);
        rgBody2D.AddForce(mousePos * speed * Time.deltaTime);

    }
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps your order of operations has something to do with it? You shoot and then you set `finalSpeed` afterwards. I don't really know when `Start()` gets called, but if it is called before `Instantiate` returns to the caller, then you're setting finalSpeed too late.

Comment: did you make sure you didnt set the value in the game object? The variable is public, so you might have set a standard value to the gameobject

Comment: Hi, I see you are using the [tag:unityscript] tag, please note that this is (as explained in the tag info) a deprecated scripting language made by Unity, and not an encompassing term for all scripts in Unity. Your question is about C# (and I have thus removed it for you). Please only use this tag if you're working on legacy code using the actual language UnityScript. This keeps the question and tags in line with each other :)

Comment: thank a lot, i'm new with stackoverflow, sorry, but my problem still not solve :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different to what others said here you actually do **NOT** want to do it in `Update`.

Your goal here is to **once** give your newly spawned arrow a start velocity, not a continuous force.

The issue here is of other nature I think:

1. You are always spawning a **new** instance of your second script from a given prefab. This prefab seems to hold a reference to a `Ballista` **prefab** instance. At least you are never assigning a new value to the `ballista`! It might simply be a wrong reference where the `finalSpeed` is never updated.
2. Your are first doing the `Shoot` and after it set the `finalSpeed` -> even if it would be the correct reference you always get the wrong `finalSpeed` value!

I would actually change your two scripts in order toake your arrow instance being controlled by the `Ballista` instead of letting each spawned arrow poll the speed itself:

```
public class Ballista : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    // By giving it the correct type here you don't need GetComponent later
    public Rigidbody2D arrowPrefab;

    public float startTimeHold;
    public float arrowSpeed = 100f;

    // I personally would add aax value and clamp since to fast RigidBodies can break collision detection eventually
    public float maxArrowSpeed = 300;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            startTimeHold = Time.time;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.M))
        {
            var holdDownTime = Time.time - startTimeHold;
            // get the speed before you shoot
            // Here personally I would clamp to be sure the arrow is never faster than maxArrowSpeed 
            // regardless of how long the user held the button pressed
            var finalSpeed = Mathf.Min(holdDownTime * arrowSpeed, maxArrowSpeed);

            Debug.Log("holddowntimeis: " + holdDownTime);
            Debug.Log("final speed is: " + finalSpeed);
            // pass in your speed
            Shoot(finalSpeed);         
        }
    }
    
    private void Shoot(float speed)
    {
        // Instantiate anyway returns the type of the given prefab
        // which now is a Rigidbody2D
        var arrow = Instantiate(arrowPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        // Directly set the speed from here
        // -> your arrow doesn't even need an extra component
        // Since you already spawned it with the correct rotation you maybe don't even need the mouse position thing
        // AddForceRelative adds a force in the local space of the arrow so if the rotation is correctly
        // this simply adds the force in its forward direction
        // Note that also using Time.deltaTime actually only makes sense if you set something continuously
        // For a one-time force you wouldn't need it, rather adjust your arrowSpeed field
        arrow.AddForceRelative(Vector2.forward * speed);
    }
}
```

Instead of using `AddForce` or `AddForceRelative` you could actually also simply set the target velocity:

```
arrow.velocity = Vector2.forward * speed;
```

Since you are not updateding it continuously this is totally fine and a lot easier to foresee the actual target speed since when adding a force you have to take the mass and frictions into account. You would than ofcourse have to adjust the `arrowSpeed` (and evtl `maxArrowSpeed`) accordingly to not anymore represent a force but an actual velocity in Units/second.

I hope I made my points clear enough, don't hesitate to ask if something stayed unclear ;)

Comment: thank you so much, i totally got you point, but i am getting trouble here.
i can not add or set my prefab after instantiate it, which is the arrow prefab.
I mean in my Shoot()  function, i can not write like "arrow.velocity...." or like your help, which is "arrow.AddForceRelative(Vector2.forward * speed);", what did i miss here
I am new to C# and unity so i think my concern is kind of silly, sorry.

Comment: alright, my script works now, thank you so much for advice, i put arrowGO.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(mousePos * finalSpeed * Time.deltaTime); after instantiate arrowPrefab, everything is fine now, again. Thank you so much hugo

Comment: as said make the type of the prefab `Rigidbody2D` like in `public Rigidbody2D arrowPrefab;` then you don't need the GetComponent since `Instantiate` will already return a `Rigibody2D` as well

Answer (score 1):

[`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) happens only once.

> Start is called on the frame when a script is enabled just before any
> of the Update methods are called the first time.

Disregarding everything else, i am guessing you want it to update the `speed` every frame in [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html)

> Update is called every frame, if the MonoBehaviour is enabled.

```
private void Update()
{
    \\ i though the code below will set my speed equal to my finalSpeed but it still 0
    speed = ballista.GetComponent<Ballista>().finalSpeed;

    Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
    Debug.Log("speed: " + speed);
    rgBody2D.AddForce(mousePos * speed * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

Comment: i did put it on update and my speed is still at zero, i tried to print all the variable on the console, all works fine but not my Speed variable :(

Comment: @Kanna So are you saying you see the log entry `speed: 0` ?

Comment: yes, for entire time, i am trying to figure out why it still at 0, sorry i am new to c#

Comment: As I understand OP's code it actually **should** happen only exactly once .. you don't apply a continuous force when shooting an arrow but only once ...

Comment: @derHugo you are correct, though i think the problem is somewhere else with such a simple issue, ill upvote your answer anyway as it makes sense (the question doesnt). Also everything should be in ECS anyway

Comment: @TheGeneral those are some strange points you make ^^ .. the question does make sense, otherwise why would you have answered? ;) And I don't think everything should be in ECS .. this would depend a lot on the use case amd how many arrows are there at the same time .. the implementation overhead for ECS might not be worth it for such a simple thing :)

Comment: @derHugo my point was, the question was about why was speed 0, if the op had done as suggested the speed would not be 0. Whether that is right or wrong or they can code an actual game is besides the point. Oh the ECS comment was about, monobehaviours are a spaghetti trap, with all the new good stuff in unity these days and data driven design, one really needs to start with the right approach first. Annnyway, we could talk all day about the pros and cons of this questions and data driven design, and what the op actually wants. I have pretty well given up on the qustion. good luck :)

Comment: "As I understand OP's code it actually should happen only exactly once" - derHugo
That is actually what i want it happen here, like I throw my Arrow, which is Instantiate arrowPrefab, and after that, my Arrow script will force it with a speed and direction depend on my mousePosition and Speed that i get from another scripts.
LIKE you throwing a grenade.
// what is ECS mean, sorry i'm new.

Answer (score 1):

**speed = ballista.GetComponent().finalSpeed;**

should Come in

```
void Update(){

}
```

block and not in

```
void Start() {

}
```

as void start is only run once and at that point in time the speed is zero
Hope it helped :)

Comment: As I understand OP's code it actually **should** happen only exactly once .. you don't apply a continuous force when shooting an arrow but only once ...